# Azure Mobile Services 'Unexpected Communication failure'

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, azure-mobile-services

I am having an issue with Azure Mobile Services using Cordova in VS2013.  When trying to insert data into a table, I am getting a 'unexpected communication failure' message.  Here is the code:

```
     document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );

function onDeviceReady() {
    // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
    document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
    document.addEventListener( 'resume', onResume.bind( this ), false );
    var RUTable = RUServicesClient.getTable('ruclientmsg');

    var test = { id: "12345" };
    RUTable.insert(test).then(onSuccess,onError);


    // TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.
};   
function onSuccess(scc)
{
    console.log("Success")
}
function onError(err)
{
    console.error(err);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I should note that I see API requests on the Azure dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by disabling cross-domain proxy in the Ripple emulator.  I think it has something to do with the CORS setting in Azure.